# MongoDB: "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 500ms miliseconds, giving up."

Tags: mongodb

I've recently installed MongoDB from their website and upon starting it through cmd get:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-11-04T17:39:09.992+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2017-11-04T17:39:09.992+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :

connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mongo` program is your **client**, not the **server**. So, when you ran `mongo` it attempted to connect to a mongo server at the default address (`127.0.0.1:27017`) and since no server was available at that address this error message was returned:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed
```

If you want to start the server then use `mongod`. For example:

```
mongod --dbpath=/path/to/your/data/directory --logpath=/path/to/your/log/directory/mongod.log'
```

And once the server has started up you can use `mongo` to run the Mongo Shell to connect to that server.

More details in the docs about [running `mongod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/) and about [running `mongo`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/).

Comment: Got this...
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongod --dbpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4 --logpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\S
erver\3.4
Invalid command: Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4"

Comment: You have supplied a dbpath with a space in it (between Progam and Files) ... `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4`, that won't work. Just run `mongod` with no arguments and accept the defaults. Then, if you want to move away from the defaults, read [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/) to understand what values you should supply.

Comment: Create the directory C:\data\db and re run